# Converting index to name pandas for graphing

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, indexing, graph

I have a dataframe and want to graph it.

[image: ]]

However when I graph it, it gives index name instead of the country's name. How can I put the country name instead of index?

[image: ]]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create `index` from column `country` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then use [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
e.set_index('country')['total_serving'].plot.bar()
#same as
#e.set_index('country')['total_serving'].plot(kind='bar')
```

Or use [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
e.plot.bar(x='country', y='total_serving')
#same as
#e.plot.bar(x='country', y='total_serving', kind='bar')
```